# How to turn a tokio TcpStream into a Sink/Stream of Serializable/Deserializable values?

Tags: rust, serde, rust-tokio

I have a tokio [`TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.18.2/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html). I want to pass some type `T` over this stream. This type `T` implement [`Serialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.137/serde/trait.Serialize.html) and [`Deserialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.137/serde/trait.Deserialize.html). How can I obtain a [`Sink<T>`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html) and a [`Stream<T>`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html)?

I found the crates [tokio_util](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.7.2/tokio_util/) and [tokio_serde](https://docs.rs/tokio-serde/0.8.0/tokio_serde/), but I can't figure out how to use them to do what I want.

Comment: You linked to an old version of `futures`.

Comment: What is the framing of the stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know your code structure or the codec you're planning on using, but I've figured out how to glue everything together into a workable example.

Your `Sink<T>` and `Stream<Item=T>` are going to be provided by the [`Framed`](https://docs.rs/tokio-serde/0.8.0/tokio_serde/struct.Framed.html) type in `tokio-serde`. This layer deals with passing your messages through `serde`. This type takes four generic parameters: `Transport`, `Item` (the stream item), `SinkItem`, and `Codec`. `Codec` is a wrapper for the specific serializer and deserializer you want to use. You can view the provided options [here](https://docs.rs/tokio-serde/0.8.0/tokio_serde/formats/index.html). `Item` and `SinkItem` are just going to be your message type which must implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize`. `Transport` needs to be a `Sink<SinkItem>` and/or `Stream<Item=Item>` itself in order for the frame to implement any useful traits. This is where `tokio-util` comes in. It provides [various `Framed*` types](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/codec/index.html#structs) which allow you to convert things implementing `AsyncRead`/`AsyncWrite` into streams and sinks respectively. In order to construct these frames, you need to specify a codec which delimits frames from the wire. For simplicity in my example I just used the [`LengthDelimitedCodec`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/codec/length_delimited/struct.LengthDelimitedCodec.html), but there are other options provided as well.

Without further adieu, here's an example of how you can take a `tokio::net::TcpStream` and split it into an `Sink<T>` and `Stream<Item=T>`. Note that `T` is a result on the stream side because the serde layer can fail if the message is malformed.

```rs
use futures::{SinkExt, StreamExt};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tokio::net::{
    tcp::{OwnedReadHalf, OwnedWriteHalf},
    TcpListener,
    TcpStream,
};
use tokio_serde::{formats::Json, Framed};
use tokio_util::codec::{FramedRead, FramedWrite, LengthDelimitedCodec};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyMessage {
    field: String,
}

type WrappedStream = FramedRead<OwnedReadHalf, LengthDelimitedCodec>;
type WrappedSink = FramedWrite<OwnedWriteHalf, LengthDelimitedCodec>;

// We use the unit type in place of the message types since we're
// only dealing with one half of the IO
type SerStream = Framed<WrappedStream, MyMessage, (), Json<MyMessage, ()>>;
type DeSink = Framed<WrappedSink, (), MyMessage, Json<(), MyMessage>>;

fn wrap_stream(stream: TcpStream) -> (SerStream, DeSink) {
    let (read, write) = stream.into_split();
    let stream = WrappedStream::new(read, LengthDelimitedCodec::new());
    let sink = WrappedSink::new(write, LengthDelimitedCodec::new());
    (
        SerStream::new(stream, Json::default()),
        DeSink::new(sink, Json::default()),
    )
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8080")
        .await
        .expect("Failed to bind server to addr");

    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let (stream, _) = listener
            .accept()
            .await
            .expect("Failed to accept incoming connection");
        
        let (mut stream, mut sink) = wrap_stream(stream);

        println!(
            "Server received: {:?}",
            stream
                .next()
                .await
                .expect("No data in stream")
                .expect("Failed to parse ping")
        );

        sink.send(MyMessage {
            field: "pong".to_owned(),
        })
            .await
            .expect("Failed to send pong");
    });

    let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080")
        .await
        .expect("Failed to connect to server");

    let (mut stream, mut sink) = wrap_stream(stream);

    sink.send(MyMessage {
        field: "ping".to_owned(),
    })
        .await
        .expect("Failed to send ping to server");
        
    println!(
        "Client received: {:?}",
        stream
            .next()
            .await
            .expect("No data in stream")
            .expect("Failed to parse pong")
    );
}
```

Running this example yields:

```
Server received: MyMessage { field: "ping" }
Client received: MyMessage { field: "pong" }
```

Note that it's not required that you split the stream. You could instead construct a `tokio_util::codec::Framed` out of the `TcpStream`, and construct a `tokio_serde::Framed` with a `tokio_serde::formats::SymmetricalJson<MyMessage>`, and then that `Framed` would implement `Sink` and `Stream` accordingly. Also a lot of the functionality in this example is feature-gated, so be sure to enable the appropriate features according to the docs.

Comment: Thanks. What's the relationship between `tokio_util::codec::Framed` and `tokio_serde::Framed`?

Comment: `tokio_util::codec::Framed` frames an underlying raw IO object and delimits raw message data within its stream/sink. `tokio_serde::Framed` frames a stream/sink of raw message data according to some serializer/deserializer. Composing these frames within each other allows you to bridge the gap between a `T: Serialize + Deserialize<'de>` and a `TcpStream`.

Comment: Are putting more than one `tokio_serde` frame into one `tokio_util::codec` frame?